# Emscripten: replacing prompt with console (of some sort)

Tags: javascript, html, emscripten

I have (interactive - like python shell) C++ console application and went playing with Emscripten (to transcompile from C++ to JS). All is well, but I'd like the JS's focus-stealing prompt to be replaced with something less... eccentric.

What I've tried: I added an input textarea and a button to generated html, and replaced the prompt-invoking line with a while loop (looping until user the button is pressed). This didn't work very well, the empty loop froze the browser (which is probably expected, but there is no sleep function in JS).

So, in short, what I want is this layout:

```
output textarea / output textarea / output textarea / output textarea
output textarea / output textarea / output textarea / output textarea
output textarea / output textarea / output textarea / output textarea
output textarea / output textarea / output textarea / output textarea

input textarea <ok button>
```

and behaviour:

```
while (1)
  let program work until input requested
  wait for user to clik on the <ok button> above
```

Any simple way to achieve this by modifying the (emcc's) generated JS code? (I have an idea how to achieve this by modifying (my) original code, but would like to avoid that if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are actually trying to do.

Please read the Emscripten documentation about [Browser limitations](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/guidelines/browser_limitations.html) first, though.

You can use `window.setTimeout` to register a callback every N milliseconds and do your *output textarea*.

And if you want to "wait" for user input it's best to give control to the browser main loop and on button click call a callback, which resumes processing (using the text input).

Comment: I'm trying to replace the JS's prompt (invoked on my request to read from stdin) with textarea+button combination. I'm aware of your solution, but it'd be nice if there was some integrated way of achieving this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Frankly I think the user experience with forms is vastly different than reading from a console. So I think it is understandable, why this will probably never be _integrated_.

Comment: I agree that what I'd like to have is way too specific to be integrated in the Em, but what might get integrated is a mechanism to  replace prompt with something more suitable, without heavily modifying the structure of output code.